# how do I query multiple tables with a specific name tha I get from a text field?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to query a textfield with a name in it the textbox is RegName, I want to get the name and select information from a MySQL database with 5 tables each table has a field DogId that relates to an individual dog. I want to get the information for the dog with the name in the textfield. Then I fill in textfields wit the information I got from the query. My problem seems to be the last 2 lines of the select statement (From doginfo
                                      Where RegName = ' " +dn+ " ');
Again RegName is the textfield with the name I am looking for. I have tried everything I can think of and have spent days looking for an answer any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code

```
       // This is where we get the information on a dog based on its Name.
     @FXML
     private void querybyNameActionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {                                                

    // Query the db for record with dog name equal to the name in regName.
    String user = "root";
      String password = "";
      String dn = null;  


      dn = RegName.getText().trim();  // dn = dog name.

     try {

        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kennelmanagment1", user, password);

        // Create statement.
         Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();


        // Execute query.

        ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT d.DogId, d.RegNum, d.RegName, d.WhelpDate, d.DNA, d.Notes, a.Breed, a.Sex, a.color, s.SireRegName, b.DamRegName, o.LastName, c.CoOwnerNames, o.Address1, o.Address2, o.City, o.State, o.Zip, o.Htel, o.Cell \n"
                + "FROM doginfo d LEFT JOIN dogat a \n"
                + "ON d.DogId = a.DogId \n"
                + "LEFT JOIN sires s \n"
                + "ON d.DogId = s.DogId \n"
                + "LEFT JOIN dams b \n"
                + "ON d.DogId = b.DogId\n"
                + "LEFT JOIN owners o\n"
                + "ON d.DogId = o.DogId\n"
                + "LEFT JOIN coowners c\n"
                + "ON d.DogId = c.DogId"
                +" FROM doginfo"
                + "Where RegName = ' " +dn+ " '");


       //System.out.println (dn);
       // System.out.println ("SELECT * FROM doginfo WHERE Regname = '" + dn + " '  ");

        // Process the result.
        while (myRs.next ()) {
             DogId.setText (myRs.getString("DogId"));
             RegNum.setText (myRs.getString ("RegNum"));
             RegName.setText(myRs.getString ("RegName"));
             WhelpDate.setText (myRs.getString("WhelpDate"));
             Breed.setText (myRs.getString ("breed"));
             Sex.setText (myRs.getString ("sex"));
             Color.setText (myRs.getString ("color"));
             SireRegName.setText (myRs.getString ("SireRegName"));
             DamRegName.setText (myRs.getString ("DamRegNName"));
             Owner.setText (myRs.getString ("Owner"));
             CoOwners.setText (myRs.getString("CoOwners"));
             Address1.setText (myRs.getString ("Address1"));
             Address2.setText (myRs.getString ("Addess2"));
             City.setText (myRs.getString("City"));
             State.setText (myRs.getString ("State"));
             Zip.setText (myRs.getString ("Zip"));
             DNA.setText (myRs.getString ("DNA"));
             HTel.setText (myRs.getString ("HTel"));
             Cell.setText (myRs.getString ("Cell"));
             Notes.setText (myRs.getString ("Notes"));
        }

        }  catch (Exception  e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, "Error");
      }    



}
```

Comment: An example would help.

Comment: I don't know how to make it any clearer. I want to get the name out of a textfield and search a database for the the information on that name once I get the data I want to put it into the textfields, I just can't get the select statement ot work. here's my error message (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RegName = ' Desiree '' at line 11)

Comment: I tried removing the line that you suggested but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the second last line since you already mentioned the table in first line.
Try removing "FROM doginfo" in second last line of your query.
Try Removing that and it should work.

Comment: this would be better suited as a comment. The OP has not given a clear picture of what they are trying to do.

Comment: Mike sorry see comment above. I'm not sure how I would give an example since this is a pretty large program. As above I am having a problem getting the select statement to work.

Comment: I think you should specify alias before column name in your query 'something.Regname' name if column exists in multiple tables.
Sorry Mike! I am new to the community.